# How to identify endpoints in convex polytopes with more variables than constraints?

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

For example, consider the set

$$S_1 = \left\{  (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^3 : x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 2 \right\}$$

Adding slack variables, we obtain

$$x_1 +x_2 +x_3 +x_s = 2$$

If we had $3$ equations, we would solve the system and find an extreme point, but in this case we have infinitely many solutions. Which of those are extreme points?

Consider that all variables involved are nonnegative.

---

**Additional:** This question arose because

$$S_2 = \left\{ (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^2 : x_1+x_2 \leq 2 \right\}$$

has no extreme points. However, for this case we can directly show that it really has no extreme points, and I know that $S_1$ has extreme points.

Comment: I don't think the set $S_1$ has extreme points. Additionally, once you include the slack variable $x_s$, you need to add the nonnegativity constraint $x_s \geq 0$. Did you mean to add the nonnegativity constraints $x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0$?

Comment: S_1 has extreme points, at least this is the exercise, proving that it does have extreme points.
And yes, I had forgotten about non-negativity

Comment: Please do let me know if you agree with my edits or if I have distorted the spirit of the original question.

Comment: $S_2$ would seem to have the obvious extreme points $(0,0),(0,2),(2,0)$.